# Parse.com - Returning multiple values from a Cloud Code function

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a Cloud Code function which will return multiple values. Now what I'm doing is

```
response.success({val1 : scores1, val2: scores2});
```

And according to the Cloud Code logs everything going well. But what I don't know is what kind of object I should cast it when I handle function in my Swift code.

```
    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("myFunction", withParameters: ["value" : 1) { (object:AnyObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
       //what I should cast object for
    }
```

I also have a thought it my mind that it can be a wrong approach as of I'm basically trying to find Swift equivavelnt to a javascript object. If so, is there any other way of returning multiple values from Cloud Code function?

I have the following in my console log when I println the object.

```
Optional({
poetry = 1;
rap = 9;
})
```

Comment: The Swift equivalent to JSON is the Dictionary... Please execute NSLog("\(object)") and post the output here... Than I could say you how to cast this object

Comment: updated the questiong with the required information

Comment: Well ok, thanks I got it, I needed to cast it to `Dictionary<String, Int>`. I'll accept that as the answer, just post it.

Comment: Yes thats it :-) I have posted you the right Code and how to access the Values as an Answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then your Object is an Dictionary Optional... You can use this Code:

```
if let responseJSON: [String: Int] = object as? [String: Int] {
      let poetryValue: Int = object["poetry"] as Int
      let rapValue: Int = object["rap"] as Int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return one object that has properties for each return value or an array of values or a dictionary (or whatever floats your boat ;)) and deserialize it on the client. This way you only have one return value that contains all the data you need conveniently massaged in to an object/list/dictionary/whatever...

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("myFunction", withParameters: ["value" : 1) { (object:AnyObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if let values = object as! [String:Int] {
    // Do something
    }
}
```

should work

Comment: I'm already doiing so in this line `response.success({val1 : scores1, val2: scores2});` I don't know how to deserealize it.